# Components as slot content Vue3

Tags: vue.js

I wonder how to add components as slot content. Instead of doing it like:

```
<template v-slot:content>CONTENT HERE</template>
```

I'd like to pass a component.

PkDynModalCenter:

```
<div class="...">
    <div id="modalIndicator" class="...">
        <slot name="content"></slot>
    </div>
</div>
```

Parent:

```
<PkDynModalCenter v-if="togglePayment" @closeModal="togglePayment = false">
        <PaymentTemplate :info="voucherInfo" name="content"></PaymentTemplate>
</PkDynModalCenter>
```

But it's not displayed. Docs are very vague there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the docs for named slots: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html

You can only use your parent code with the default slot, so your PkDynModalCenter should look like this:

```
<div class="...">
    <div id="modalIndicator" class="...">
        <slot></slot> <!-- no name → default slot -->
    </div>
</div>
```

With your current code for the modal, you can only call it like you did in your first code snippet.

Comment: But how about props?
When passing one I get the error:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable`. The data is available.

Comment: You should be able to pass props to your components as usual. Which props are failing to pass? Although, if you want to pass props from your modal to the slot when rendering, you would need to use slotProps (same docs page, ScopedSlots) and with that you would need to use a `<template #default="slotProps">...</template>` again as a child to access the slotProps.

Comment: It's the `info` prop throwing the error. Even if I just use dummy-data:
`<PaymentTemplate :info="{test: 1}"...`

Comment: Okay.. I changes this: `props: { info: {  type: JSON, required: false }}`  to that `props: {info: JSON},` and now the props work. Weird but I'll accept it.

Comment: That's a weird way of passing props though. Do you want to post your full component code somewhere (in an edit, some pastebin or sth like that)? Maybe you did not define the props correctly.

Comment: Why is it weird? It's even like that in the vue documentary. I just don't use the `defineProps` macro. Here's a bin: https://pastebin.com/QSQsBgin

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you were passing props that way. But your are defining them as stated in the comment. No that's totally fine that way. And I see your point, normally defining props like you wanted to do (with `required: false`) should work. Which Vue version and which API are you working with? (Composition or Options)

Comment: I'm using Vue 3.2.41. So one of the latest versions. It should work like that. Passing them like this in other components works just fine. Maybe it's some side-effects of slots.